# ZipArchive Multile Files/Folders

Tags: php, zip, directory, hierarchy

I have three files `hash_a.php`,`hash_b.php`,`/morefiles/hash_c.php` in root directory.

I want to zip it to client and stream it but not in that manner.

I want to send the client something like

**FILE.ZIP**

```
root
|_folder1
  |_a.php 
  |_b.php
  |_c.php
```

is it possible using php ?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: yes i got it i didnt read ziparchive docs sorry lol

Comment: "yes i got it"--has your question been resolved?

Comment: I havent written it yet once i write ill tell.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to create a function something like the below code. And pass all the files to the function.

```
function create_zip($files = array(),$destination = '',$overwrite = false) {
    //if the zip file already exists and overwrite is false, return false
    if(file_exists($destination) && !$overwrite) { return false; }
    //vars
    $valid_files = array();
    //if files were passed in...
    if(is_array($files)) {
        //cycle through each file
        foreach($files as $file) {
            //make sure the file exists
            if(file_exists($file)) {
                $valid_files[] = $file;
            }
        }
    }
    //if we have good files...
    if(count($valid_files)) {
        //create the archive
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        if($zip->open($destination,$overwrite ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true) {
            return false;
        }
        //add the files
        foreach($valid_files as $file) {
            $zip->addFile($file,$file);
        }
        //debug
        //echo 'The zip archive contains ',$zip->numFiles,' files with a status of ',$zip->status;

        //close the zip -- done!
        $zip->close();

        //check to make sure the file exists
        return file_exists($destination);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

After creating the function. Pass the files to the function which you need to be zip. The code will looks like this.

```
$files_to_zip = array(
    'preload-images/1.jpg',
    'preload-images/2.jpg',
    'preload-images/5.jpg',
    'kwicks/ringo.gif',
    'rod.jpg',
    'reddit.gif'
);
//if true, good; if false, zip creation failed
$result = create_zip($files_to_zip,'my-archive.zip');
```

This code will make the .Zip file with the files that you need.